# Como puedo colocar contenido o undiv dentro de una imagen

Tags: javascript, html, css

Me gustaria colocar un slider dentro de esta imagen

```html
<body>
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcROcTxwl91VI2513ToAlo713TUks44f5XQ6QexkNWKWhkiqr9V-" alt="">
</body>
```

Comment: Tu pregunta no es clara, a que te refieres con "dentro de esta imagen", una imagen es un archivo, no puedes crear nada "dentro" de la imagen

Comment: En todo caso tendrias que crear tus imagenes con la forma necesaria y posicionarlas de manera que "encajen" dentro de la silueta del dispositivo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capaz esto se sirva, Solo descarga la libreria de nivo-slider para que funcione: [https://github.com/Codeinwp/Nivo-Slider-jQuery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGOQi.png) 
Una vez descargada lo descomprimes junto al HTML y eso es todo.
Solo coloca tus imagenes pero ten encuenta que deben ser de 135px de ancho y 140px de alto, ya que se necesita usar medias para que quede exacto con el modelo de la imagen, pero si deseas intenta jugar con las medidas que están en el Style. 
Todo esta en el HTML.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Consulta</title>
<link href="Nivo-Slider-jQuery-master/themes/default/default.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<link href="Nivo-Slider-jQuery-master/nivo-slider.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  

<style>
.conten-slider{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 position: relative;
}
.slider-wrapper{
 position: absolute;
}
#slider{
 width:130px; // Aqui puedes alterar el tamano de la imagen
 height: 135px; // Aqui puedes alterar el tamano de la imagen
 margin: 0;
 box-shadow: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="conten-slider">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcROcTxwl91VI2513ToAlo713TUks44f5XQ6QexkNWKWhkiqr9V-" alt="">
  <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
   <div id="slider">    
       <img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-N3Pxv_dxAY8/T5H1aL3BqQI/AAAAAAAAASE/5DCjgnCwjKs/s150/facebooknewtab.jpg">    
       <img src="https://www.finelib.com/images/listings/53533_company_logo.JPG"> 
       <img src="https://www.brownbagmarketing.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/b_banner.png"> 
       <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0049/7693/5025/files/smaller_instagram_image_300x300.png?v=1556323691"> 
   </div>
  </div> 
 </div>
</body>

<script src="nivoslider/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 $(window).on('load', function() {
  $('#slider').nivoSlider({
     controlNav: false, 
  }); 
 }); 
</script>
</html>
```

Quedaría algo así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]